# Parameter Sniffing causing slowdown for text-base query, how to remove execution plan?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a sql query, the exact code of which is generated in C#, and passed through ADO.Net as a text-based SqlCommand.

The query looks something like this:

```
SELECT TOP (@n)
        a.ID,
        a.Event_Type_ID as EventType,
        a.Date_Created,
        a.Meta_Data
FROM net.Activity a

LEFT JOIN net.vu_Network_Activity na WITH (NOEXPAND)
ON na.Member_ID = @memberId AND na.Activity_ID = a.ID

LEFT JOIN net.Member_Activity_Xref ma
ON ma.Member_ID = @memberId AND ma.Activity_ID = a.ID

WHERE 
    a.ID < @LatestId 
AND ( 
        Event_Type_ID IN(1,2,3))
        OR 
        (
            (na.Activity_ID IS NOT NULL OR ma.Activity_ID IS NOT NULL) 
            AND 
            Event_Type_ID IN(4,5,6)
        ) 
    )
ORDER BY a.ID DESC
```

This query has been working well for quite some time. It takes advantage of some indexes we have on these tables.

In any event, all of a sudden this query started running really slow, but ran almost instantaneously in SSMS.

Eventually, after reading several resources, I was able to verify that the slowdown we were getting was from poor parameter sniffing.

By copying all of the parameters to local variables, I was able to successfully reduce the problem.  The thing is, this just feels like all kind of wrong to me.

I'm assuming that what happened was the statistics of one of these tables was updated, and then by some crappy luck, the very first time this query was recompiled, it was called with parameter values that cause the execution plan to differ?

I was able to track down the query in the Activity Monitor, and the execution plan resulting in the query to run in ~13 seconds was:

[image: execution plan run from web app... ~13s]

Running in SSMS results in the following execution plan (and only takes ~100ms):

[image: execution plan run from SSMS... ~100ms]

#### So what is the question?

I guess my question is this:  How can I fix this problem, without copying the parameters to local variables, which [could lead to a large number of cached execution plans](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/#comment-448910)?

Quote from the [linked comment / Jes Borland](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/#comment-448910):

> You can use local variables in stored procedures to “avoid” parameter sniffing. Understand, though, that this can lead to many plans stored in the cache. That can have its own performance implications. There isn’t a one-size-fits-all solution to the problem!

My thinking is that if there is some way for me to manually remove the current execution plan from the temp db, that might just be good enough...  but everything I have found online only shows me how to do this for an actual named stored procedure.

This is a text-based SqlCommand coming from C#, so I do not know how to find the cached execution plan, with the sniffed parameter values, and remove it?

Note: the somewhat obvious solution of "just create a proper stored procedure" is difficult to do because this query can get generated in a number of different ways... and would require a somewhat unpleasant refactor.

Comment: Does net.activity have member_id in it?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson no, it does not. Why?

Comment: Could have swapped the two left joins on @member_id to members.member_id one less parameter to sniff though I suspect Top(@n) is causing you the most significant problem, having had another look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove a specific plan from the cache then it is really a two step process:  first obtain the plan handle for that specific plan; and then use DBCC FREEPROCCACHE to remove that plan from the cache.

To get the plan handle, you need to look in the execution plan cache.  The T-SQL below is an example of how you could search for the plan and get the handle (you may need to play with the filter clause a bit to hone in on your particular plan):

```
SELECT top (10)
    qs.last_execution_time,
    qs.creation_time,
    cp.objtype, 
   SUBSTRING(qt.[text], qs.statement_start_offset/2, ( 
       CASE  
           WHEN qs.statement_end_offset = -1 
                THEN LEN(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), qt.[text])) * 2  
           ELSE qs.statement_end_offset  
       END - qs.statement_start_offset)/2  + 1
   ) AS query_text, 
   qt.text as full_query_text, 
   tp.query_plan,
   qs.sql_handle,
   qs.plan_handle
FROM  
   sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs 
   LEFT JOIN sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp ON cp.plan_handle=qs.plan_handle
   CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text (qs.[sql_handle]) AS qt 
   OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(qs.plan_handle) tp 
WHERE qt.text like '%vu_Network_Activity%'
```

Once you have the plan handle, call DBCC FREEPROCCACHE as below:

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE(<plan_handle>)
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer!  I'm giving this a shot and will report back.

Comment: This ended up working as advertised. Note: I removed the left join + outer apply in the query to find the plan handle, as the query was too slow with those in it.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to [delete/invalidate a query plan](http://sqlhint.com/sqlserver/query-plan/delete-or-invalidate-query-plan):

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE(plan_handle)
```

or

```
EXEC sp_recompile 'net.Activity'
```

or

adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` query hint at the end of your query

or

using `optimize for ad hoc workloads` server settings

or 
updating statistics

Answer (score 0):

If you have a crappy product from a crappy vendor, the best way to handle parameter sniffing is to create you own plan using EXEC sp_create_plan_guide/